# BeautifulSoup Not parsing div class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to process this page:

```
https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=3B6EBBD94D13B4DCMV
```

I'm using the following code to read HTML:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

def read_html(url):
  try:
     res = requests.get(url)
     if res.status_code == 200:
        html_content = res.content
        soup = BS(html_content)
        return _get_type(soup)           
      else:
        print res.status_code
  except ValueError, e:
     print e


def _get_type(soup):   
  """Read Movie.""" 

  mydivs = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "DBzzzb"})
  if mydivs:
    return 'AVAILABLE'

  mydivs = soup.findAll("span", {"class": "DBzzzb"})
  if mydivs:
    return 'PREORDER'

  mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "Wc4pU"})
  if mydivs:
    return 'NOT_AVAILABLE'

  return 'INVALID'
```

My condition never matches: `soup.findAll("div", {"class": "Wc4pU"}` even though there is in fact the HTML Code there:

```
<div class="Wc4pU">We'll notify you on your wishlist when movies become available</div>
```

Source HTML:

```
view-source:https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=3B6EBBD94D13B4DCMV
```

Comment: You should use `bs4`

Comment: Changing to BS4 worked!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a parser :

```
soup = BS(html_content, 'html5lib')
```

This makes the process much faster too.